# Using Pandas Multiindex with quantities fails with 'Categorical levels must be unique'

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas MultiIndex with indices having quantities fails in some cases. Let me show you an example:

```
import quantities as pq
import pandas as pd

i = np.arange(10) * pq.J
j = np.array([1 for _ in xrange(10)]) * pq.K

pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(i, j), names=['Energy', 'Temperature'])
```

This fails with the following traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-c2d09517b80e> in <module>()
      5 j = np.array([1 for _ in xrange(10)]) * pq.K
      6 
----> 7 pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(i, j), names=['Energy', 'Temperature'])

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in from_tuples(cls, tuples, sortorder, names)
   1685 
   1686         return MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, sortorder=sortorder,
-> 1687                                       names=names)
   1688 
   1689     @property

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in from_arrays(cls, arrays, sortorder, names)
   1646             return Index(arrays[0], name=name)
   1647 
-> 1648         cats = [Categorical.from_array(arr) for arr in arrays]
   1649         levels = [c.levels for c in cats]
   1650         labels = [c.labels for c in cats]

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\categorical.pyc in from_array(cls, data)
     59 
     60         return Categorical(labels, levels,
---> 61                            name=getattr(data, 'name', None))
     62 
     63     _levels = None

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\categorical.pyc in __init__(self, labels, levels, name)
     45     def __init__(self, labels, levels, name=None):
     46         self.labels = labels
---> 47         self.levels = levels
     48         self.name = name
     49 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\categorical.pyc in _set_levels(self, levels)
     68         levels = _ensure_index(levels)
     69         if not levels.is_unique:
---> 70             raise ValueError('Categorical levels must be unique')
     71         self._levels = levels
     72 

ValueError: Categorical levels must be unique
```

If I remove the units, it works just fine.

```
i = np.arange(10)
j = np.array([1 for _ in xrange(10)])

pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(i, j), names=['Energy', 'Temperature'])
```

If I keep the units, but use a unique item for j, it works as well.

```
i = np.arange(10) * pq.J
j = np.arange(10) * pq.K

pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(i, j), names=['Energy', 'Temperature'])
```

This is of course no option since the indices come from a measurement. I'd really like to keep the units, but since I'm not familiar with pandas internals I don't know how to fix this.

### Versions

I'm using pandas version 0.10.1 and quantities 0.10.1 in python 2.7.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the exception on version 0.10.0.  Which release was this seen on?

Comment: @crewbum Updated with version info.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce this error, but it is intermittent
on Linux, failing every few invocations of
`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(...)`.

I believe the error is due to `quantity` objects violating
the Python equality-hashing invariant of `a==b` implies `hash(a)==hash(b)`
(sources: http://bugs.python.org/issue13707#msg150596, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sympy/pJ2jg2csKgU/0nn21xqZEmwJ).

An example of bad hashing behavior.

```
In [5]: (1 * pq.K) == (1 * pq.K)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: hash(1 * pq.K) == hash(1 * pq.K)
Out[6]: False
```

Based on this behavior, I believe this is a quantities issue, which
leads to an illegal internal state in pandas.

IMO, the cleanest solution would be for quantity objects to return a consistent hash based
on the current value, much like this (rejected) pull request to add a `__hash__()` function on quantity objects:
https://github.com/python-quantities/python-quantities/pull/29.
Either that, or throw an error on an attempt to hash, if it wants
to behave like a mutable object.

Comment: But how does it work when the quantity is ommited? Does pandas use the hash function? I thought numpy arrays raise a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` when one tries to hash them.

Comment: Yes, pandas uses hash.  When quantity is omitted, pandas sees an array of `int` objects, which adhere to the equality-hash rule mentioned.  It seems that even though quantity is a subclass of ``ndarray`` it does not raise a TypeError when hashed.

Comment: Would converting the quantity to a string, i.e., ``zip(map(str, i), map(str,j))``, be an acceptable workaround?